# Font size in PGFPlots Minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fontsize, minipage

I am using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235372/how-to-get-vector-graphics-from-concorde-program) guide to put concorde tsp solver's vector graphics in LaTeX. I want to show 2 images and a description text right next to them, all side-by-side. I am usign the minipage to do so, but I am having some trouble with the font size of the edges' weights.

Here is the code:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=\textwidth, compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
[...]
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.32\textwidth}
    \def\callforme#1 {%
    \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
        \resizebox {.6\columnwidth} {!} {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [node/.style={draw=blue, circle, fill=white, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0.8pt},
    nodetext/.style={node, text height=2ex, text depth=0.5ex, font=\small\bfseries},
    line/.style={black},
    tour/.style={red},
    linetext/.style={fill=white, circle, inner sep=0.5pt, outer sep=0pt, font=\tiny},
    ]
    \input #1
    \end{tikzpicture}}}
\input {fortex.tex}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.32\textwidth}
\def\callforme#1 {%
    \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
        \resizebox {.6\columnwidth} {!} {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [node/.style={draw=blue, circle, fill=white, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0.8pt},
    nodetext/.style={node, text height=2ex, text depth=0.5ex, font=\small\bfseries},
    line/.style={black},
    tour/.style={red},
    linetext/.style={fill=white, circle, inner sep=0.5pt, outer sep=0pt, font=\footnotesize},
    ]
    \input #1
    \end{tikzpicture}}}
\input {fortex2.tex}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.32\textwidth}
    Ecco un esempio dove l'algoritmo greedy produce un risultato tutt'altro che buono.
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Here is the output:
[image]

I tried a couple of things but none of them seems to be working, the font of the edges is still too big.

I am loooking for a solution that doesn't modify the default height of the images because I have a lot of other plots above and I don't wanna change them.

So far I tried defining a new custom font size smaller than tiny, I tried using scale, transform shape,.. and a couple of other..but none of them works.

EDIT:...
fortex.tex

```
\callforme concorde1-3-output.tex
```

concorde1-3-output.tex

```
\begin{axis}[xmin=35.683761, xmax=53.490028, ymin=8.847737, ymax=97.119342,
axis equal image, enlargelimits]
\coordinate (1) at (axis cs: 42.877493, 10.082305);
\coordinate (2) at (axis cs: 47.079772, 21.810700);
\coordinate (3) at (axis cs: 42.521368, 35.185185);
\coordinate (4) at (axis cs: 46.652422, 45.884774);
\coordinate (5) at (axis cs: 42.094017, 58.641975);
\coordinate (6) at (axis cs: 46.509972, 69.753086);
\coordinate (7) at (axis cs: 52.849003, 58.847737);
\coordinate (8) at (axis cs: 53.133903, 34.156379);
\coordinate (9) at (axis cs: 53.490028, 8.847737);
\coordinate (10) at (axis cs: 35.683761, 20.987654);
\coordinate (11) at (axis cs: 35.683761, 45.267490);
\coordinate (12) at (axis cs: 35.826211, 71.604938);
\coordinate (13) at (axis cs: 47.150997, 97.119342);
\coordinate (14) at (axis cs: 52.635328, 82.921811);
\draw [line] (1)--(2) node [linetext,pos=0.5] {12};
\draw [line] (1)--(9) node [linetext,pos=0.5] {11};
\draw [line] (2)--(10) node [linetext,pos=0.5] {11};
\draw [line] (3)--(8) node [linetext,pos=0.5] {11};
\draw [line] (3)--(4) node [linetext,pos=0.5] {11};
\draw [line] (4)--(11) node [linetext,pos=0.5] {11};
\draw [line] (5)--(7) node [linetext,pos=0.5] {11};
\draw [line] (5)--(6) node [linetext,pos=0.5] {12};
\draw [line] (6)--(12) node [linetext,pos=0.5] {11};
\draw [line] (7)--(11) node [linetext,pos=0.5] {22};
\draw [line] (8)--(10) node [linetext,pos=0.5] {22};
\draw [line] (9)--(13) node [linetext,pos=0.5] {88};
\draw [line] (12)--(14) node [linetext,pos=0.5] {20};
\draw [line] (13)--(14) node [linetext,pos=0.5] {15};
\node [node] at (1) {};
\node [node] at (2) {};
\node [node] at (3) {};
\node [node] at (4) {};
\node [node] at (5) {};
\node [node] at (6) {};
\node [node] at (7) {};
\node [node] at (8) {};
\node [node] at (9) {};
\node [node] at (10) {};
\node [node] at (11) {};
\node [node] at (12) {};
\node [node] at (13) {};
\node [node] at (14) {};
\end{axis}
```

fortex2.tex

```
\callforme concorde2-7-output.tex
```

concorde2-7-output.tex

```
\begin{axis}[xmin=35.683761, xmax=53.490028, ymin=8.847737, ymax=97.119342,
axis equal image, enlargelimits]
\coordinate (1) at (axis cs: 42.877493, 10.082305);
\coordinate (2) at (axis cs: 47.079772, 21.810700);
\coordinate (3) at (axis cs: 42.521368, 35.185185);
\coordinate (4) at (axis cs: 46.652422, 45.884774);
\coordinate (5) at (axis cs: 42.094017, 58.641975);
\coordinate (6) at (axis cs: 46.509972, 69.753086);
\coordinate (7) at (axis cs: 52.849003, 58.847737);
\coordinate (8) at (axis cs: 53.133903, 34.156379);
\coordinate (9) at (axis cs: 53.490028, 8.847737);
\coordinate (10) at (axis cs: 35.683761, 20.987654);
\coordinate (11) at (axis cs: 35.683761, 45.267490);
\coordinate (12) at (axis cs: 35.826211, 71.604938);
\coordinate (13) at (axis cs: 47.150997, 97.119342);
\coordinate (14) at (axis cs: 52.635328, 82.921811);
\draw [tour] (1)--(10);
\draw [tour] (10)--(3);
\draw [tour] (3)--(11);
\draw [tour] (11)--(5);
\draw [tour] (5)--(12);
\draw [tour] (12)--(13);
\draw [tour] (13)--(14);
\draw [tour] (14)--(6);
\draw [tour] (6)--(7);
\draw [tour] (7)--(4);
\draw [tour] (4)--(8);
\draw [tour] (8)--(2);
\draw [tour] (2)--(9);
\draw [tour] (9)--(1);
\node [node] at (1) {};
\node [node] at (2) {};
\node [node] at (3) {};
\node [node] at (4) {};
\node [node] at (5) {};
\node [node] at (6) {};
\node [node] at (7) {};
\node [node] at (8) {};
\node [node] at (9) {};
\node [node] at (10) {};
\node [node] at (11) {};
\node [node] at (12) {};
\node [node] at (13) {};
\node [node] at (14) {};
\end{axis}
```

Comment: Without files `fortex` and `fortex2` we can't obtain output.

Comment: @salimbou added the two files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With key `scale=0.2` (or what will convince you) you can reduce size for every `linetext`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=\textwidth, compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
[...]
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.32\textwidth}
    \def\callforme#1 {%
    \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
        \resizebox {.6\columnwidth} {!} {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [node/.style={draw=blue, circle, fill=white, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0.8pt},
    nodetext/.style={node, text height=2ex, text depth=0.5ex, font=\small\bfseries},
    line/.style={black},
    tour/.style={red},
    linetext/.style={fill=white, circle,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,font=\tiny,scale=.2},
    ]
    \input #1
    \end{tikzpicture}}}
\input {fortex.tex}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.32\textwidth}
\def\callforme#1 {%
    \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
        \resizebox {.6\columnwidth} {!} {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [node/.style={draw=blue, circle, fill=white, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0.8pt},
    nodetext/.style={node, text height=2ex, text depth=0.5ex, font=\small\bfseries},
    line/.style={black},
    tour/.style={red},
    linetext/.style={fill=white, circle, inner sep=0.5pt, outer sep=0pt, font=\footnotesize},
    ]
    \input #1
    \end{tikzpicture}}}
\input {fortex2.tex}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.32\textwidth}
    Ecco un esempio dove l'algoritmo greedy produce un risultato tutt'altro che buono.
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

For files `fortex` and `fortex2` no changes

**Output**

[image]